# MongoDB Find Check If Exists not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, error-handling

I have a MongoDB query I'm running in NodeJS below that not supposed to run (doc) if there the query returns null:

```
collection.find( { name: "HOSTNAME_1" }, {$exists: true}).sort( { _id : -1 } ).limit(1).toArray(function(err, doc){
  if (doc) {
    res.write("event: add" + '\n');
    res.write("data: " + JSON.stringify(doc).substr(1,JSON.stringify(doc).length-2) + "\n\n");
  } else if (!doc) {
    console.log("No Entry Found!");
  }
});
```

For some reason it still runs the doc function and outputs this when I curl it.

```
event: add
data:
```

If I remove the `.toArray` so my query looks like this:

```
db.clients.find( { name: "HOSTNAME_1" }, {$exists: true}).sort( { _id : -1 } ).limit(1)
```

It returns null like it is supposed to and if I run it against an item that actually does exists it returns `{ "_id" : ObjectId("12345689randomnumber") }` like it is supposed to.  Something with the `.toArray` is butchering my `{$exist:true}` error-handle.

How do I "error handle" this in one query without having to write an if else statement outside of the query? Thanks c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it but looking at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/), toArray returns array which I assume would return an empty array `[]` when there's no result? If that's the case, then `if([])` actually returns true in javascript which explain it.

Comment: I saw this when I ran it inside Mongo but I didn't think anything of it. My error handle needs to be based around if (doc) = []  I suppose. Thanks for pointing this out Bill!